# The FastCGI process exited unexpectedly

Tags: php, windows-server-2008

I am trying to run PHP via FastCGI on a Windows 2008 server.

I followed this installation doc http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/246/using-fastcgi-to-host-php-applications-on-iis7/ and have checked I completed the steps correclty numerous times.

However when I try to execute a php page i am presented with the following error:

HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error
C:\PHP\php-cgi.exe - The FastCGI process exited unexpectedly

Comment: possible duplicate of [IIS 7.5 PHP failure "The FastCGI process exited unexpectedly"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11992153/iis-7-5-php-failure-the-fastcgi-process-exited-unexpectedly)

Comment: I restarted fastcgi settings, handler mappings, CGI from IIS Manager(Windows 10) and it showed my test php page.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You might be using **C:/[your-php-directory]/php.exe** in **Handler mapping** of IIS just change it **C:/[your-php-directory]/php-cgi.exe**.

Comment: I knew I mis-configured something. All other settings and software dependencies were there, and executing a PHP file from command-line was working. However, only IIS was throwing the FastCGI run-time error.

Comment: This worked for me.Could not believe changing from "php.exe" to "php-cgi.exe" made it worked. Also I made the change on sub directory like mydir/mysuba/mysubB in the handler mapping. Thank you Akshay Khale

Answer (score 87):

maybe you should try installing VC++ runtime as explained [here](https://serverfault.com/a/613940/76947).

> There's a fairly good chance you're missing the correct VC++ runtime for the version of PHP you're running.
>
> If you're running PHP 5.5.x you need to ensure the VC++11 runtime is installed:
>
> http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679
>
> Make sure you download and install the x86 version (vcredist_x86.exe), PHP on Windows isn't 64 bit yet.
>
> If you're running PHP 5.4.x then you need to install the VC++9 runtime:
>
> http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5582

Comment: Thank you. It works. For PHP 5.6, also please do same as 5.5.x

Comment: That was it for me as well on Azure VM Server 2012 R2! Thank you!

Comment: Huge help! This worked for me installing 5.6 on Windows 2012. I installed the x86 version using your first link. After that it just worked. Thanks

Comment: That did it for me!

Comment: For PHP 7.x it's VC++ 15. It was necessary to install both 64bit and 32bit versions, even the windows server was 64bit.

Comment: if problem doesnt solve, try running php-cgi.exe directly (cmd line) as mentioned by Akshay Khale and get to know the message. in my case it was VC++ 14

Answer (score 36):

When you run php-cgi.exe from the dos command line, you will get the missing MSVCR110.dll pop up message.

Like Ben said, Get the x86 download for the dll here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679

Comment: THANK you for saving my life!

Comment: Thanks for specifying x86, I got the wrong version the first time :)

Comment: Worked for me too. Server was running IIS Express.

Comment: THIS SHOULD BE THE CORRECT ANSWER IT WORKS

Comment: For me, it showed an info about an obsolete config flag - removing it solved my problem (installed redists beforehand)

Answer (score 16):

After much pain and suffering, turns out I needed to install the "Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012 Update 4  32-bit version", even on my 64-bit server.

Comment: Yes exactly. I had installed PHP 5.6 on IIS on Windows server 2012 R2. Didn't work after x64 VC++ but worked after x86 and restarting IIS.

Comment: Yes, this is required. I think as the php is 32 bit on windows that is why x86 version of c++ redistributable package is required to be installed. If the server(computer) is 64 bit then it is better to install both version (64bit and 32bit) of visual c++  redistributable package.

Comment: What a pain.  Visual C++ Redistributable errors are like the old Win 3.1 DLL conflicts all over again.  Needed to uninstall all the ones I already had, then install them all again starting from oldest and working up to newest.  Solved the problem though!

Comment: Yep, this fixed it. Specifically it had to be the 32bit (x86) version.

Answer (score 11):

If you are installing PHP 7.1.14 on windows server 2008 rc2 Enterprise, only thing worked for me is to install **microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable Update 3** from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53587

Comment: Worked for me on Windows Server 2016, PHP version 7.1, thanks...

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me on Windows 2012 standard server. Cheers!

Answer (score 9):

I tried opening php-cgi.exe directly and it gave me a more clear error message.

Answer (score 3):

As the answer of 'sepehr' this issues are because of VC++ Redistributable suitable version for PHP are not installed or need to be reinstalled again.

I faced it before so i'll explain my steps to fix it.

1- Each PHP version is built by a specific Visual C++ Redistributable version like (10, 11,12,14,..) what ever. 
((How you know!! look.. ))

- Check back [enter link description here](http://windows.php.net/) The PHP Site then at the left side of this page, look at "Which version do I choose?" then see what version of VC++ is fits your PHP version installed.
- Now YOU HAVE TO Download both of VC++ 32 and 64. and if your PC has it already then Unistall them first. and then install what you downloaded recently bu 
  (first 32 then 64).

*- VC download links are exists on the mentioned PHP Site on the left side also.*

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Nice - I installed the VC redists - but version thing I got to know from your comments. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

if you have two application like (your app, phpmyadmin) just disable APC extension
Hope that fix that issue
it's worked with me

Answer (score 1):

For user using PHP 5.6.x follow this [link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=30679) and install the x86 version.

Answer (score 1):

I have installed the latest version of Visual C++ Redistributable from [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-160) for php 8.0.0 x86:

and my problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was coming through the application pool. Try to change your application pool ASP.NET v4.0.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had wrong constellation of configurations:

- error reporting disabled
- typo error in the configuration

After enabling the error_reporting it was clear the session_path was pointed to a wrong folder.

"Sad but true"

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this same error installing PHP 7 on Windows Server 2008 R2. I resolved this by installing the Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: And It's necessary to install x86 version, x64 wouldn't solve the 500 error but x86 fix it totally

Answer (score 0):

For Issue **C:\PHP\php-cgi.exe - The FastCGI process exited unexpectedly.**

I resolved this by installing the **Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015.(Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable Update 3)** and **Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012 Update 4 in 32 and 64bit** versions. and also make sure in php.info file *cgi.fix_pathinfo=0* enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error too after I changing PHP version in windows.
I have PHP Manager plug in of IIS installed, it show the PHP is not enabled, then I fix this issue after doing "Register new PHP version"
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I struggled for hours with that problem, and no solution worked for me. May seems obvious or very foolish, but my error was in PHP 5.6 version. I was using PHP 5.6 from XAMPP, but if you download PHP on IIS with Web PI (Microsoft Web Platform Installer) it's more suitable for IIS instead XAMPP version.

More Info:

https://stackify.com/how-to-host-php-on-windows-with-iis/

Answer (score 0):

Running php-cgi.exe from the command line gave a message like the vcrt dll is a lower version than what is linked in php.
Using Visual C++ redistributable package 64 bit 14.29 solved the above problem for me.