# installing PHP 5.5.15 on Windows Server 2008 r2 64bit

Tags: php, iis-7.5

THe last time I installed PHP there was a great install program. Now I guess I have to do this version manually, So

I am trying to install PHP 5.5.15 on a Windows Server 2008 r2 64 bit and I am getting no where. I have followed the instruction multiple times and no dice.

If I try to check PHP by typing ...testphp.php into IE I get the following error:

HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error

C:\PHP\php-cgi.exe - The FastCGI process exited unexpectedly

Detailed Error Information 
Module
FastCgiModule

Notification
ExecuteRequestHandler

Handler
PHPFast_CGI

Error Code
0xc0000135

IF I try to check using the Command Line I get error that says MSVCR110.dll is missing. I have installed MS Visual C++ 2010 x64 red... and also tried installing MS Visual C++ 2012 x64 red... and that did not fix the problem.

What am I doing wrong?

Steps used
Set up IIS 
Download PHP (non thread safe), unzip to php folder
added Module Map...(FastCGIModule)
try to test php
also tried to modify the php.ini file before testing and no dice

Comment: did you check the windows error log to see what is going on?

Comment: Checked this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11992153/iis-7-5-php-failure-the-fastcgi-process-exited-unexpectedly

Comment: I could not get 5.5.15 PHP to work so I had to go with 5.4.x and it seems to work so far.

Answer (score 1):

Install the 32 bit version of VC11 or 9 from Microsoft. PHP is most likely 32 bit unless you selected the experimental version of PHP from their site - regardless of your OS type. I think that might solve your problem.

BUT...

I can't get php 5.5 to work on IIS 7.5 and Windows. I've tried for several days and I get 404.3 module handler or MIME type missing. No matter what the hell I do.