# IIS PHP Contact Form - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error

Tags: php, html, forms, iis, fastcgi

I have a template I downloaded and with it came a PHP form. When submitting the form the console shows: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

HTML:

```
  <form action="contact-form.php" method="POST" class="contact-form">
                  <ul class="row">
                    <li class="col-md-6 form-item">
                      <label for="contact-name"><i class="ico-male"></i></label>
                      <input type="text" name="contact-name" class="contact-name" id="contact-name" value="Your Name" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Your Name'" onfocus="if(this.value=='Your Name')this.value=''">
                    </li>
                    <li class="col-md-6 form-item">
                      <label for="contact-email"><i class="ico-email"></i></label>
                      <input type="email" name="contact-email" class="contact-email" id="contact-email" value="Your Email" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Your Email'" onfocus="if(this.value=='Your Email')this.value=''">
                    </li>
                    <li class="col-md-12 form-item">
                      <label for="contact-message"><i class="ico-bubble"></i></label>
                      <textarea name="contact-message" class="contact-message" id="contact-message" data-placeholder="Your message"></textarea>
                    </li>
                    <li class="col-md-12 form-item">
                      <input type="submit" name="contact-btn" class="contact-btn general-link" id="contact-btn" value="Send Your Message">
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </form><!-- end of contact form -->
```

PHP:

```
<?php

if($_POST["submit"]) {

    $fromEmail      =  strip_tags($_POST['contact-email']);
    $fromName       =  strip_tags($_POST['contact-name']);
    $themessage     =  strip_tags($_POST['contact-message']);
    $themessage     =  $themessage."The Sender Is ( ".$fromName." )" ; 



    $toEmail = 'jh@gmail.com';
    $toName = 'JH';

    Mail::send('emails.contactus', $data , function($message) use ($toEmail, $toName, $fromEmail, $fromName, $subject)
    {
        $message->to($toEmail, $toName);

        $message->from($fromEmail, $fromName);

        $message->subject($subject);
    });

$headers = 'From:' .$fromName . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To:' .$fromEmail. "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();



if(mail($toEmail, $subject, $themessage, $headers))
{

      // Send 
echo "success";

}
else{ echo "An error has be occured"; }
}

?>
```

I am doing this locally on IIS Server and receiving this.

Edit:

It is showing the error HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error
C:\Program Files\PHP\v7.0\php-cgi.exe - The FastCGI process exited unexpectedly

I have gone through the fixes that are shown on other answers such as:

[The FastCGI process exited unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23007551/the-fastcgi-process-exited-unexpectedly)

> You might be using C:/[your-php-directory]/php.exe in Handler mapping of IIS just change it C:/[your-php-directory]/php-cgi.exe.

[IIS 7.5 PHP failure "The FastCGI process exited unexpectedly"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11992153/iis-7-5-php-failure-the-fastcgi-process-exited-unexpectedly)

> To fix it I had to install the Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012 Update 3

It's still showing the same error. Not sure how to resolve this now.

Comment: Turn on error reporting and find out what is causing it

Comment: @Epodax thanks see above

Answer (score 0):

Check the coding of your form part .